# ruby regexp to find a word that does not contain digits

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I want my regular expression to return an enumerator that would return blocks with words that are not digits, what is the best way I could get that?

I have tried following:

```
regexp= /(?=\w+)(?=^(?:(?!\d+).)*$)/
"this is a number 1234".split(regexp) # ["this is a number 1234"]
```

where I expected (?=\w+) should ensure if that is word or not and I expected (?=^(?:(?!\d+).)*$) to ensure it does not contain any digits.

I expected an output:

```
["this", "is", "a", "number"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`scan` is easier than `split` for this:

```
regexp = /\b[[:alpha:]]+\b/
p "this is a number 1234".scan(regexp)
# => ["this", "is", "a", "number"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following.

```
p "this is a number 1234".scan(/\D+/).first.split(' ')
```